# How to solve tokennizer char stream segmentation error?

Tags: c++

Hello I'm  beginner we it cames to c/c++ and I'm suppose to develop a programming language for both Theory of computing class and my Principle of programming language(named easia) to do so i need to start from scratch but i have encountered a mysterious segmentation problem that i'm struggling with for 4 days now
here are the codes

```
//header  file
//This library is suppose to contain all the needed defined data type for the project
#ifndef TOOLBOX_H
#define TOOLBOX_H 
#include <string>

// using namespace std;


class C_stream//This class is implementing a stack that represent the input 
 {
    void add(char c);
    void inflate();
 public:
    int  count, unit, filled;
    int top =0;
    char *stream;
    char read(int i=0);
    C_stream();
    ~C_stream();
    void extract(std::string file);
    int size();
    void print();
    void preprocess();

 }; 
 class tags
  {
  public:
    int AND=256, BASIC=257,BREAK=258, DO=259, AS=260,Long=261,GE=262,
        EQ=263,ID=264,WHEN=265,INDEX=265,LE=267,MINUS=268,PLUS=269,TIME=270,DIVIDE=271,NUM=272,NE=273,OTHER=274,
        OR=275,REAL=276,TEMP=277,True=278,CASE=279,Float=280,KEY_W=281,Id=282,ASSIGN=283,STRING=284,
        FUNCTION=284;
    tags(){}
    ~tags(){}
  };



//   }; tag{
//      AND=256, BASIC,BREAK, DO, AS,Long,GE,
//      EQ,ID,WHEN,INDEX,LE,MINUS,PLUS,TIME,DIVIDE,NUM,NE,OTHER,
//      OR,REAL,TEMP,True,CASE,Float,KEY_W=257,Id,ASSIGN

// }Tag;


 class Token
 {
 public:
    int line,tag;
    Token();
    Token(int t,int l);
    virtual std::string toString();

 };


 class Num:public Token{
 public:
    int value;
    Num();
    Num(int val, int l);

    std::string toString();

 };

 class Float:public Token{
 public:
    float value;
    Float(float val, int l);

    std::string toString();
 };


 class STR:public Token{
    int count;
    std::string val;
 public:
    STR();
    STR(std::string v,int n, int l);

    std::string toString();

 };

 class Word:public Token{
    int val=0;
 public:
    std::string lexeme;

    Word();
    Word(std::string lexi,int tag,int l);///
    Word(std::string lexi,int l=0);

    std::string toString();

 };




class Table{
Word** keyWords; 
int count;
public:
    Table();
    ~Table();
    void add(Word*w);
    bool get(std::string w);
    Word* give(std::string s);
};

class Num_stack{
    int* numb = new int[5],count=0,sz=5;
    void inflate();
public:
    Num_stack();
    ~Num_stack();
    bool check(int j);
    void push(int i);
    int top();
    int pop(int i=1);
    int size();


};


class T_stream{
    int  count, unit, filled;
    void inflate();

public:
    Token* *stream;
    T_stream();
    ~T_stream();
    void add(Token*t);
    void add(Token* t ,  int n);
    Token* read(int i);
    int size();
    void show();

};


class Lexer{
    void error(std::string s);
    void error(std::string s,int li);
public:
    Table t;
    C_stream c;
    Lexer(C_stream c);
    T_stream scan();

};


 #endif
```

now the attached file implementing the classes

```
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "Toolbox.h"

using namespace std;

tags Tag;
int numoro=0;

    void C_stream::inflate(){
        filled++;
        char* n_stream = new char[filled*unit];
        memcpy(n_stream,stream,count);
        delete [] stream;
        stream = n_stream;
    }


    C_stream::C_stream(){
        count=0,unit=100,filled=1;
        stream = new char[filled*unit];

    }
    C_stream::~C_stream(){
        if (count>0)
        {
            delete [] stream;
        }
    }

    void C_stream::add(char c){
        if(count < (filled*unit)){
            stream[count++]=c;
        }else{
            inflate();
            stream[count++]=c;
        }
    }
    void C_stream::print(){
        cout<<stream<<endl;
    }

    char C_stream::read(int i){
        return stream[0+i];
    }

    int C_stream::size(){
        return count;
    }


    void C_stream::extract(std::string file){
        ifstream in(file);
        char c;
        while(in.get(c)){
            add(c);
        }
    }

    void C_stream::preprocess(){
        int l_count=0;
        char *t_stream = new char[count];
        int i = 0;
        while(i<count)
        {
            switch (stream[i]){
                case'#':
                    while((stream[i]!='\n')&&(i<count)){
                        i++;
                    }
                    t_stream[l_count++]=stream[i++];
                    break;
                case'<':
                        if (stream[i+1]=='<'){//try to increment i by two before entering in the loop


                            i+=2;
                            while((stream[i-1]!='>')&&(stream[i-2]!='>')&&(i<count))
                                i++;

                            i+=1;
                        }

                        t_stream[l_count++]=stream[i++];
                        break;

                default:
                    t_stream[l_count++]=stream[i++]; 

                    break;
            }
        }
        char *n_stream = new char[l_count];
        memcpy(n_stream,t_stream,l_count);
        delete [] t_stream;
        stream = n_stream;
    }

    Token::Token():line(0),tag(0){
    }

    Token::Token(int t, int l):line(l),tag(t){

    }

    std::string Token::toString(){
        std::string go="";
        if((tag<128) and (tag!='\n') and (tag!='\t') ){
            go=static_cast<char>(tag);
        }else{
            switch(tag){
                case('\n'):
                    go=" \\n ";
                    break;
                case('\t'):
                    go=" \\t";
                    break;
                default:
                    go=to_string(tag);
            }

        }
        return "token tag: "+go+" l:"+std::to_string(line)+" ";
    }



    Num::Num():value(0){

    }

    Num::Num(int val, int l):value(val){
        Token(Tag.NUM,l);
    }

    std::string Num::toString(){
        return "Num:"+std::to_string(value)+" ";
    }

    Float::Float(float val, int l):value(val){
        Token(Tag.REAL,l);
    }

    STR::STR(): count(0),val(""){
        Token();
    }
    STR::STR(std::string v,int n, int l):count(n),val(v){
        Token(Tag.STRING,l);
    }
    std::string STR::toString(){
        return " string of"+std::to_string(count)+" char: "+val;
    }

    std::string Float::toString(){
        return "Float:"+std::to_string(value)+" ";
    }
    Word::Word():lexeme(""){

    }
    Word::Word(std::string lexi,int ta,int l):lexeme(lexi){
        Token(ta,l);
    }

    Word::Word(std::string lexi,int l):lexeme(lexi){
            Token(Tag.KEY_W,l);
    }


    std::string Word::toString(){
        return "Word:"+lexeme;
    }


    Table::~Table(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
        {
            delete [] keyWords[i];
        }
        delete [] keyWords;
    }


    Table::Table(){
        count=0;
        keyWords = new Word*[30];
        add(new Word("as"));
        add(new Word("gives"));
        add(new Word("for"));
        add(new Word("and"));
        add(new Word("try"));
        add(new Word("long"));
        add(new Word("other"));
        add(new Word("going"));
        add(new Word("or"));
        add(new Word("do"));
        add(new Word("show"));
        add(new Word("bring"));
        add(new Word("from"));
        add(new Word("del"));
        add(new Word("catch"));
        add(new Word("func"));
        add(new Word("to"));
        add(new Word("case"));
        add(new Word("in"));
        add(new Word("Break"));


    }

    void Table::add(Word* w){

        keyWords[count++]=w;


    }

    bool Table::get(std::string w){
        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i){
            if(keyWords[i]->lexeme==w)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    Word* Table::give(std::string s){
        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i){
            if(keyWords[i]->lexeme==s)
                return keyWords[i];
        }
    }


    Num_stack::~Num_stack(){
        delete [] numb;

    }


    bool Num_stack::check(int j){

        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        {
            if(numb[i]==j)
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    void Num_stack:: inflate(){

        sz=count*2;
        int* n_num = new int[sz];
        memcpy(n_num,numb,count);
        delete [] numb;
        numb = n_num;

    }


    void Num_stack::push(int t){

        if(count<sz){
            numb[count++]=t;
        }else{
            for (int i = 0; i < sz; ++i){
                cout<<" "+numb[i];
            }
            cout<<endl;
            inflate();//increasing the size of the stack
            numb[count++]=t;
            for (int i = 0; i < sz; ++i){
                cout<<" "+numb[i];
            }
        }

    }

    int Num_stack::top(){ //returns the top of the stack

        return numb[count];

    }
    int Num_stack::pop(int i){
        if(i==1){
            count--;
            return numb[count+1];
        }else{
            count=0;
            return numb[count];
        }

    }

    int Num_stack::size(){
        return count;
    }


     Num_stack::Num_stack(){
        numb[count++]=0;
     }




    void T_stream::inflate(){
        filled++;
        Token* *n_stream = new Token*[filled*unit];
        memcpy(n_stream,stream,count);
        delete [] stream;//take care of the multi dimensionnal deletion
        stream = n_stream;
    }

    T_stream::T_stream(){
        count=0,unit=100,filled=1;
        stream = new Token*[filled*unit];

    }
    T_stream::~T_stream(){
        if (count>0)
        {
            delete [] stream;//take care of the multi dimensionnal deletion
        }
    }

    void T_stream::add(Token* t){
        if(count < (filled*unit)){
            stream[count++]=t;
        }else{
            inflate();
            stream[count++]=t;

        }
    }

    void T_stream::add(Token*t ,  int n){
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            add(t);
        }
    }




    Token* T_stream::read(int i){
        return stream[0+i];
    }

    int T_stream::size(){
        return count;
    }

    void T_stream::show(){
        std::string n = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
            n+="   |";
            n+=stream[i]->toString();
            n+="|   ";
            if ((i%5==0)&&(i>0)){
                n+="\n";
            }
        }
        cout<<n<<endl;
    }

    Lexer::Lexer(C_stream cs){
        c= cs;
    }


    void Lexer::error(std::string s,int li ){
        cout<<"LEXICAL error:"<< s <<": "<< to_string(li)<<" "<<endl;
    }

    void Lexer::error(std::string s ){
        cout<<"LEXICAL error:"<< s <<endl;
    }

    T_stream Lexer::scan(){
        int line=1;
        int i=0;
        bool begin=false;
        int indent=0;
        T_stream tokens;
        Num_stack n ;
        int ival=0;
        float fval=0;
        std::string Wo="";
        int prev=0;
        cout<<"The scanner method" <<endl;
        while(i<c.count){
            numoro++;
            if (!begin){
                if(c.read(i)==' '){
                    error("no space should be at the begining of a line",line);
                }
            }else{
                if((c.read(i)==' ')||(c.read(i)=='\t')){
                    i++;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            if (isdigit(c.read(i))){
                ival+=c.read(i++)-48;
                while(isdigit(c.read(i))){
                    ival*=10;
                    ival+=c.read(i++)-48;
                }
                if(c.read(i)=='.'){
                    fval+=ival;
                    i++;
                    float decimal=0,range=10;
                    while(isdigit(c.read(i))){
                        decimal+=c.read(i++)-48;
                        decimal=decimal*10;
                        range*=10;
                    }
                    fval+=decimal/range;
                    tokens.add(new Float(fval,line));
                    if (!begin){
                        begin=true;
                    }
                    fval=0;
                    ival=0;
                }else{
                    tokens.add(new Num(ival,line));
                    ival=0;
                    if (!begin){
                        begin=true;
                    }
                    continue;
                }

            }else{
                if (c.read(i)=='<'){
                    if (c.read(i+1)=='-'){
                        tokens.add(new Token(Tag.ASSIGN,line));
                        i+=2;

                        continue;
                    }else{
                        if (c.read(i+1)=='='){
                            tokens.add(new Token(Tag.LE,line));
                            i+=2;
                            continue;
                        }
                        tokens.add(new Token('<',line));
                        i++;
                        continue;

                    }
                }else{
                    if (c.read(i)=='>'){
                        if (c.read(i+1)=='='){
                            tokens.add(new Token(Tag.GE,line));
                            i+=2;
                            continue;
                        }
                        tokens.add(new Token('>',line));
                        i++;
                        continue;

                    }else{
                        if((isalpha(c.read(i))||('_'==c.read(i)))){
                            Wo+=c.read(i++);
                            while((isalpha(c.read(i)))||('_'==c.read(i))||(isdigit(c.read(i)))){
                                Wo+=c.read(i++);
                            }
                            if (t.get(Wo)){
                                tokens.add(t.give(Wo));
                            }else{
                                tokens.add(new Word(Wo,line));
                            }
                            begin=(begin==false)? true:true; 
                            Wo="";
                            continue;
                        }else{
                            if(c.read(i)=='\n'){
                                line++;
                                tokens.add(new Token('\n',line));
                                i++;
                                begin=(begin==true)?false:false;
                                if(c.read(i)!='\t'){
                                    n.pop(0);
                                }
                                continue;
                            }else{
                                if ((c.read(i)=='\t')&&(!begin)){
                                    indent++;
                                    i++;
                                    while(c.read(i)=='\t'){
                                        indent++;
                                        i++;
                                    }

                                    if (n.top()<=indent){
                                        tokens.add(new Token('\t',line),indent);
                                        n.push(indent);
                                        indent=0;
                                        continue;

                                    }else{
                                            tokens.add(new Token('\t',line),indent);
                                            n.push(indent);
                                            indent=0;
                                            continue;
                                    }
                                }else{
                                    tokens.add(new Token(c.read(i++),line));
                                    if (!begin){
                                        begin=true;
                                        }

                                }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        cout<<numoro<<endl;
        return tokens;

    }
```

here is the calling file

```
#include "Toolbox.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    C_stream Chars = C_stream();
    Chars.extract("codeTest.easia");
    Chars.print();
    Chars.preprocess();
    Chars.print();
    Lexer lex(Chars);
    T_stream t=lex.scan();
    t.show();
    return 0;
}
```

and finally the file on which the processing is performed on

```
a<-4+3+5+7

b<-a 

for i going from 0 to 5:
    if a=b:<<this is also a comment that is suppose to be on many line 
                    so we don't care about what is in here 
                    or here 
                    or her 
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    infinite :)
                    just kidding around 

    >>
        show("first")
    <<                              >>else:
        show("every thing is done")
        <<co
        mm
        ent>>
as long as (b<<<>><30)<<   >>:
    show("still lower than 30")
    b<-b+1<<   >>


# here is the end of the present test code
------------------------------------------
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: `char* n_stream = new char[filled*unit]; memcpy(n_stream,stream,count);` -- how do you prove that `count` will never be more than `filled*unit`, otherwise you're obviously corrupting memory here? That's just one example. This entire code is full of dangerous programming practices and complete absence of bounds checking. There are likely to be many other, similar instances of memory corruption. It's going to be faster to get rid of everything and rewrite the whole thing from scratch, this time using safe programming practices that use containers, and iterators.

Comment: Also, why do you use `std::string` in some places, but then resort to error-prone `char *` and `new[]` in other places?  Why not stay with `std::string` throughout your program?

Comment: `delete [] t_stream,stream;` -- What is this line of code supposed to do?  Whatever you believe it does, it doesn't do it.  -- *but i have encountered a mysterious segmentation problem* -- The segmentation error is *not* mysterious, given what you have written.  Maybe you should use `std::vector<char>`, and work with that, not `char *` and `new[]`.

Comment: ok thanks I'll try it @PaulMcKenzie